# Printing two arrays inside of a third array that has the same combined length as the first two

Tags: java, arrays

What I need to do is create a third dynamic array (I think I did) that combines the length of the first two and then prints out the contents of those arrays as the output of the third array.

Example:

Array 1:
1
4
2
6
0

Array 2:
3
6
2
1
5

Array 3:
1
4
2
6
0
3
6
2
1
5

This is what I have so far:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class DynamicArray
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // User Input - Array length
        int arrayLength;
        arrayLength = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Array length:"));

        // First dynamic array
        int[] dynArray1;
        dynArray1 = new int[arrayLength];

        for (int i = 0; i < dynArray1.length; i++)
        {
            dynArray1[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
        }

        System.out.println("First Array:");

        for (int j = 0; j < dynArray1.length; j++)
        {
            System.out.println(dynArray1[j]);
        }

        // Second dynamic array
        int[] dynArray2;
        dynArray2 = new int[arrayLength];

        for (int i = 0; i < dynArray2.length; i++)
        {
            dynArray2[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
        }

        System.out.println("Second Array:");

        for (int j = 0; j < dynArray2.length; j++)
        {
            System.out.println(dynArray2[j]);
        }

        // Third dynamic array
        int thirdArrayLength = dynArray1.length + dynArray2.length;
        int[] dynArray3;
        dynArray3 = new int[thirdArrayLength];

        for (int i = 0; i < dynArray3.length; i++)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

I would just print the first and second but I think that would be cheating and it isn't what my assignment is asking for. I was going to for loop Array1 and Array2 and println the results. I'm not exactly sure how I should go about it though. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: This has been solved! Below is the code:

```
    /* Third dynamic array */
    int thirdArrayLength = dynArray1.length + dynArray2.length;
    int[] dynArray3;
    dynArray3 = new int[thirdArrayLength];

    for (int i=0; i < dynArray1.length; i++) {
        dynArray3[i] = dynArray1[i];
    }
    for (int i=0; i < dynArray2.length; ++i) {
        dynArray3[i + dynArray1.length] = dynArray2[i];
    }

    System.out.println("Third Array:");

    for (int i=0; i < dynArray3.length; ++i) {
        System.out.println(dynArray3[i]);
    }
```

Comment: You can initialize and assign a variable in one statement, i.e. `int length = 5;` instead of `int length;` and `length = 5`.

Comment: I should've added this in the original post, the array length must be a number the user inputs.

Comment: You can edit your original post ;)

Comment: I assume that this is an assignment and you are not allowed to use any high level functions that combine the arrays for you?

Comment: @McNasty49, has any answer helped you so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to just iterate over the first two arrays and populate the third array:

```
for (int i=0; i < dynArray1.length; i++) {
    dynArray3[i] = dynArray1[i];
}
for (int i=0; i < dynArray2.length; ++i) {
    dynArray3[i + dynArray1.length] = dynArray2[i];
}

// then print out the third array
for (int i=0; i < dynArray3.length; ++i) {
    System.out.println(dynArray3[i]);
}
```

Comment: I apologize for taking so long to respond; this is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Java-8 then you can use [`Arrays`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) and [`System.arraycopy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int)):

```
//your array
int array1[] = {1, 4, 2, 6, 0};
int array2[] = {3, 6, 2, 1, 5};

//create a new array witch have length array1.length + array2.length
int array3[] = new int[array1.length + array2.length];

//copy the first array1 in array3
System.arraycopy(array1, 0, array3, 0, array1.length);
//copy the second array2 in array3
System.arraycopy(array2, 0, array3, array1.length, array2.length);

//display your arrays
System.out.println("Array 1:" + Arrays.toString(array1));
System.out.println("Array 2:" + Arrays.toString(array2));
System.out.println("Array 3:" + Arrays.toString(array3));
```

**Output**

```
Array 1:[1, 4, 2, 6, 0]
Array 2:[3, 6, 2, 1, 5]
Array 3:[1, 4, 2, 6, 0, 3, 6, 2, 1, 5]
```

Comment: Interesting answer! Haven't used `System.arraycopy` so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the third array as soon as the user inputs the first two arrays' length, then in the two `for` loops where you print their content, you can also populate the third array.

In this case you will have to pay attention at the second `for`'s counter, which will start from zero but will have to be increased because a part of the third array will already be populated.

I won't say more, since you said it's homework and don't want to cheat :)

Answer (score 0):

There's a nice Apache Commons library method for this: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.html#addAll%28T%5B%5D,%20T...%29

```
int[] dynArray3 = (int[])ArrayUtils.addAll(dynArray1, dynArray2);

for(int i : dynArray3) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java 8's `stream` to sequencially iterate over two arrays, e.g.:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    int[] array1 = {1,2,4}, array2 = {4,5,6};
    Stream.of(array1, array2)
    .flatMapToInt(s -> Arrays.stream(s))
    .forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

**Update**

If you want to merge/concat two arrays then you add a `Collector` in this stream which would generate a list, e.g.:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    int[] array1 = {1,2,4}, array2 = {4,5,6};
    List<Integer> list = Stream.of(array1, array2)
    .flatMapToInt(s -> Arrays.stream(s))
    .boxed()
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

This would give you the list of `Integer`, you can then convert it into `int[]` array like this:

```
int[] array = new int[list.size()];
for(int i=0 ; i<list.size() ; i++){
    array[i] = list.get(i);
}
```

Comment: This answer does not help OP to solve his assignment and understand the problem.

Comment: @mike thanks for pointing it out. I have added another example into the answer which will help OP solve his assignment.

Answer (score 0):

There are two (+1) possibilities.

**Loop over destination array**

You can loop over the third array once (as you currently did), and use an `if`, which helps you to determine, whether you should access the first or second array.

```
if (i > array1.length) {
    array3[i] = array2[i - array1.length];
else
    array3[i] = array1[i];
}
```

---

**Loop over both source arrays**

Or you can use two dedicated loops which loop over the first and second array and assign their values to the third. The second loop which iterates over `array2` has to use an offset for indexing the third array, though.

```
    array3[i +  array1.length] = array2[i];
```

---

**Java8's Stream API**

Use `IntStream concat(IntStream a, IntStream b)` in `IntStream` to concatenate two streams, which you can create with `java.util.Arrays.stream(int[])`.